# Syntax not valid on word 'ON' in SQL join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to run an SQL `SELECT` statement which *is* running correctly in SQL Server Management Studio, but I keep receiving the error while trying to run the below code in Visual Basic/Studio:

> In correct syntax near the word 'ON'

**Code:**

```
com = New SqlCommand("SELECT Member_Details.mMember_ID AS 'Unique ID', Member_Details.mFirst_Name + Member_Details.mLast_Name AS 'Name', CONVERT(varchar(10),Member_Details.mDoB,103) AS 'Date of Birth', Member_Details.mGender AS 'Gender', Rep_Group.rRep_Group_Name AS 'Rep Group'" & _
        "FROM Member_Details" & _
        "Join(Rep_Group) ON Member_Details.mRep_Group=Rep_Group.rRep_Group_ID", con)
```

**The error message:**

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

The SQL Statement does work without the Join statement, so I think I'm just formatting it wrong in Visual Studio.

Comment: You forgot some spaces before FROM and JOIN keywords.

Comment: Thank you @Arvo, But now it's saying the ')' is wrong. I'm not sure which one it's not liking :/

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Join(Rep_Group)` with `Join Rep_Group` in your code. `JOIN` is not a function :)

Comment: @downvoter: Please tell me the reason for down voting.

Comment: I voted your answer back up. It was correct, though I'd already noticed my mistake. It wasn't me that voted you down.